# How to access services on the docker container and host simultaneously

Tags: docker, port, grpc

I have a service on docker `8888` and a local grpc service running on `0.0.0.0:50051` and I want to connect to that port through the docker container.

Docker run command:

```
sudo docker run -ti -p 8888:8888 -p 50051:50051 -v $(pwd):<folder> -e <aws-credentials> <directory> jupyter
```

Error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: 
driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint strange_lamarr (<string>): 
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:50051: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Here the first service is ran through docker, so if I try adding `network="host"` to the command, the first service fails. I just want to use local service for the second port.

Docker is trying to use the port instead of connecting to that port, I have tried copying and creating an instance of the service on docker itself but it uses a bunch of local graphics that I cannot really replicate on docker easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port mapping `-p 50051:50051` is used when you need to access the container from the host.

When you need to access the host from the container, you need to add a hostname that's mapped to the `host-gateway`. The convention is to call it `host.docker.internal`. You do that by adding `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` as an option to your `docker run` command, so it becomes

```
sudo docker run -ti -v $(pwd):<folder> -e <aws-credentials> <directory> --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway jupyter
```

Then you can connect from the container by using the hostname `host.docker.internal` and port 50051.

Comment: Thanks, I had to be careful of what I was looking for from inside the container, had to change where I looked for the port from 'localhost:5001' to 'host.docker.internal:50051'